# "increased no cost" vs "did not increase the cost"

Tags: meaning, verbs, negation

I think this sentence is correct:

> This action increased no cost.

I can say the same as:

> This action did not increase the cost.

I prefer the former, because it's shorter.  However, could one claim that the latter is preferred?

Comment: But f irst, I suspect that neither of these is what you actually mean. Are you saying "They did not cause any increase in cost."?

Comment: After your comment I slightly edited my question: I changed "any cost" to "the cost".  There is some cost, which is a number.  The cost before and after the action was still the same, so this action increased no cost.

Comment: After the edit, tt still means there are more costs than one.

Comment: Do you mean that "increased no cost" implies there are many costs? There can be one cost, and it did not increase.

Comment: The first version is confusing.  While I agree there can be multiple costs in a complex project, one has to read the phrase 2-3 times to understand the meaning.  It is almost always clearer to place the negation ahead of the verb.

Comment: Thank you, Hot Licks, for your comment. I'll go with the second sentence. However, I had an impression that native speakers of English (I'm not one) would like the first sentence, because of the examples like: "It hurts no one.", "She bore no child." or "I gave him nothing".

Comment: Such phrasing is only preferred in terse and somewhat idiomatic statements.

Comment: All right, Hot Licks, I've got nothing more to say.  Thank you!

Comment: *No* **does** imply a plural noun. "She bore no child"= "She did not bear any **children**". The two sentences in the question bear out the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the sense of [cost](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cost) (the price) is monetary, your sentence slightly modified is offered:

> This action did not increase the monetary cost of X.

As in this sentence:

> X did not increase the cost of lumber used in the building.

Comment: Thank you, lbf, for your answer.  Your first sentence ("This action did not increase the monetary cost of X.") is basically the same as my second sentence, and I agree these sentences are correct.  However, I wondered whether my first sentence was fine.

Comment: because of the many senses of cost your 1st sentence would be fine with 'monetary for financial cost'